# Micronaut-OpenApi LocalDate custom format

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, micronaut

By default swagger shows LocalDate in "yyyy-MM-dd" format.
But I am accepting dates in "yyyyMMdd" format. How can I custamize this format? If I am not wrong, I will have to use @Schema annotation above my property. What parameters I need to mention in @Schema annotation?

Answer (score 0):

The field to use for an input (or response) format is `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema#pattern`:

```java
@Parameters({
    @Parameter(
        name = "some_date",
        description = "A special formatted date",
        schema = @Schema(type = "string", pattern = "yyyyMMdd")
    )
})
public MuttableHttpResponse<Void> someMethod(@QueryValue("some_date") Date someDate) {
    //...
}
```

*Note: the `@Schema#type` should be `string` even though you are dealing with dates values as that is the default type used for `String`s, `Date`s and `File`s.*

Comment: type= "date" gave me unsupported data type.

Comment: Excuse my error  that was the supposed name to go with, I should have replaced while posting the answer. The correct type to go with is `string`.